# Dummy DATE field with NULL value

Tags: sql, dummy-variable

I am performing a union between two tables. In order to make the two tables consistent for a UNION, I need to add a dummy column.

One table has DATE field whereas the other table does not have that field. How can I create the dummy DATE field which can either be '' (blank) or NULL?

I am trying something like this in DB2

TO_DATE('','MM/DD/YYYY') AS DUMMY_DATE

Comment: I think @vkp answer will help you,I am voting up his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select `null`.

```
select col1, datecol from table1
union all
select col1, null from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use NULL as column:

```
NULL as Dummy
```